# Could not find <UINavigationButton... in a list of sorted view with VoiceOver on

Tags: ios, voiceover

We have an app with a menu.  There is a UIBarButton that can be tapped to open it.  The top view slides away to show the menu.  When VoiceOver is turned on, we get the error below.  I'm assuming because the area that

```
2015-07-14 14:29:11.772 xxxxx[318:36506] |error| Could not find <UINavigationButton: 0x13e57db60; frame = (5 6; 40 30); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x170435ee0>> in a list of sorted view [parent: <MobileUIApplication: 0x13e6023d0>] siblings (
    "<UITableView: 0x13e8ac800; frame = (0 20; 375 647); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; autoresizesSubviews = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x17444cb10>; layer = <CALayer: 0x170436560>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {375, 680}>"
).  If this happened right around a screen change, it might be okay, but otherwise this is probably a bug.
2015-07-14 14:29:11.775 xxxxx[318:36506] |error| Could not find <UINavigationButton: 0x13e57db60; frame = (5 6; 40 30); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x170435ee0>> in a list of sorted view [parent: <MobileUIApplication: 0x13e6023d0>] siblings (
    "<UITableView: 0x13e8ac800; frame = (0 20; 375 647); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; autoresizesSubviews = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x17444cb10>; layer = <CALayer: 0x170436560>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {375, 680}>"
).  If this happened right around a screen change, it might be okay, but otherwise this is probably a bug.
```

I added    UIAccessibilityPostNotification(UIAccessibilityLayoutChangedNotification, nil); but I still get the error.

Should I be concerned and what should be done about this?

Comment: I get the same error with different view hierarchies (i.e. not UINavigationStuff), was always wondering what it is but due to lack of time never got to post a proper question to [Apple's accessibility developer mailing list](https://lists.apple.com/mailman/listinfo/accessibility-dev), I strongly suggest you do so, because an answer from Apple accessibility engineer is probably the only one that could lead to a resolution (I think no one else that an "insider" will have a clue as to what is going on).

Comment: The bug is likely caused by trying to do some accessibility in a wrong way. Can you reproduce the issue in a sample project and share some code? I am afraid there's no general rule to fix this one.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `UIAccessibilityLayoutChangedNotification` which is used to notify that layout of an element or part of the `UIView` has changed. Try using `UIAccessibilityScreenChangedNotification`.

If your tableView scrolls, you might want to use `UIAccessibilityPostNotification(UIAccessibilityPageScrolledNotification, [self.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows]);` so that every time the tableView scrolls, the focus is on the first cell of your tableView.